# Class dynamic allocated members and copying/assign, how to avoid reallocation and copy?

Tags: boost, heap-memory, shared-ptr, member

Simple question, I dont want to allocate and copy heap allocated memory every time I need to copy an object with heap pointers, its silly, I can just point the pointer to the original heap, and assure the original allocator doesnt delete the pointer.

I guess I need a reference counted pointer....witch one? I dont have experience using smart pointers, I just want one that everytime I assign it it increase the reference count, and just deletes it if reference count is 0..

Is it the case for shared_ptr? can I just close my eyes and use it?
Why not just create my own refcount_ptr that increases the reference count on assignment and check it on destructor?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pointee to be shared between the original and the copied object, you can use `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

> Why not just create my own refcount_ptr that increases the reference
>   count on assignment and check it on destructor?

Well, you can write your own `shared_ptr`, but usually it's not worth reinventing the wheel unless the existing one doesn't match your needs.

Comment: will memcmp(shared_ptr<T>, shared_ptr<T>, sizeof(T)) work as it works for raw pointers?

Comment: @Icebone1000 no, it even won't compile, because shared_ptr<T> is an object instance, not a pointer. To access the underlaying raw pointer use shared_ptr::get() member function.